# Java Apache Math Commons Element-Wise Matrix Multiplication

Tags: java, matlab, matrix

I was wondering if there is a feature in the Apache Math Commons library for element-wise multiplication similar to the one used in MATLAB being that the resulting matrix `C` is equal to each value in matrix `A` multiplied by the corresponding value in matrix `B`. I want to avoid writing my own version because I know linear algebra packages are highly optimized for these kinds of operations and I don't want to lose performance on my own implementation if one already exists (that's optimized).

In MATLAB: `C = A.*B` and `A`'s dimensions must equal `B`'s.

Comment: I'm missing the part of your question where you say you went over the [`RealMatrix` interface](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/linear/RealMatrix.html) and didn't find anything. After you did _that_ take a look [here](http://glimmpse.samplesizeshop.org/documentation/JavaStatistics/1.2/api/edu/cudenver/bios/matrix/MatrixUtils.html#getElementWiseProduct%28org.apache.commons.math3.linear.RealMatrix,%20org.apache.commons.math3.linear.RealMatrix%29).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, and I did look I can't believe I didn't find it! Thanks for clearing it up :)

Comment: note that the last link I posted is to a 3rd-party library that happens to implement what you need. No reason to feel bad :)

Answer (score 0):

I've used for RealVectors from Apache math the ebeMultiplication. I don't know if there is an equivalent function for matrices, I checked and I did not find. As for the vectors:

```
    RealVector output = new ArrayRealVector(o); // o and y are double[]
    RealVector expected = new ArrayRealVector(y);
    RealVector errors = expected.subtract(output);    
    RealVector delta = errors.ebeMultiply(output);
```